# Spring boot - Servlet-api

Tags: spring-boot

I am doing simple "Hello World" spring boot project . I don't see servlet-api implementation jar in maven dependencies list ,  From where the implementation is provided to application ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring handles all interaction with the Servlet API for you, so you are very unlikely to need to use any of it. You should study some Spring Boot tutorials.

If you use a build tool such as Maven, which you should do, the indirect dependency on Jars for the Servlet API, and much else besides, is handled automatically for you.

Spring Boot can generate a standalone executable for you, which incorporates a packaged Servlet container.

Comment: So you mean to say the dependencies ( even though there are no in build path ) implementations are provided automatically .  Initially I thought servlet container provide implementation for servelet-api.

Answer (score -1):

Servlet api implementation is expected to be provided by the servlet container to which you deploy the application ( `.jar` ) on, E.g. tomcat  (optionally downloading/running it via `spring-boot:run` maven plugin goal )

Alternatively you can create a [fat jar](https://www.baeldung.com/deployable-fat-jar-spring-boot) that contains the servlet container inside and launches it through `main()`.